# "npm" can't resolve from npm.fontawesome.com

Tags: angular, npm, bamboo, angular-fontawesome, fontawesome-4.4.0

My Angular project use module from https://npm.fontawesome.com

I call command:

```
npm --loglevel info install grun
```

local and it is fine finished, but if call this command in build-server I have an error.

.npmrc file:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=<some>
```

I have an error in build-server:

```
error   30-Jun-2020 19:54:21    npm ERR! code E401
error   30-Jun-2020 19:54:21    npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
```

What can I do? Where is my wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same `.npmrc` file on the build server?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Yes, I'm sure I'm executing command `ls -al` and see file `.npmrc` in the directory.

Comment: @Frost OK, How it can help me?

Comment: Try npm i font-awesome --save  see if that helps u.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the license allows you to work. In my case, there was a limit on the number of developers.